# Making a list and appending to it in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow. I'm not able to understand how to create a dynamic "pythonic" list in TensorFlow. Basically, I perform some computation on a tensor object (`train_data[i]`) and append it to a "list" `X`, which I want to be a tensor with shape `(100,)`

I want to do something like this:

```
X = []
for i in range(100):
    q = tf.log(train_data[i]) 
    print(q)    #Tensor("Log:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) 
    X.append(q)
```

I want `X` to be a Tensor with shape `(100,)`, basically a column vector which is a tensor object. If I run the code above, I instead get a python list of TensorObjects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to convert `X` to a (100,) tensor you could add `X = tf.stack(X)` after your for loop:

```
X = []
for i in range(100):
  q = tf.log(train_data[i]) 
  print(q)    #Tensor("Log:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) 
  X.append(q)
X = tf.stack(X)
```

This is a useful construct where you may want to `tf.unstack` some tensor, loop over the resulting list, and then  use `tf.stack` to get back to a single tensor.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out yesterday, but this is the correct answer. Another way to do is to use tf.concat(). I made a gist here : https://gist.github.com/alivcor/921b797a7f0242b9024105f128bc7da8

Comment: @AbhinandanDubey  It seems that tf.concat(x, 0) is more like "extend" but not "append". If you really need "append",  tf.stack() will be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer here is that you have to change your way of thinking a bit. In Tensorflow you first define a computational graph, and then evaluate it with values as input.

For your example: if X is indeed a Tensor with shape (100,1), tf.log(X) would work best. 
If you want to create a dynamic list like your code suggests, it would be better to create this list BEFORE passing it to the graph.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks rmeertens ! I understand that we construct graphs in TF, but my question is how can I define/initialize a list. The outcome of running above code should result in X being a (100,1) tensor. Could you be more specific about what should be done to achieve this ?

Comment: Well, if you really insist on doing it this way, you can probably use the scatter_update function: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update.

If X is already a (100,1) tensor you can try X = tf.scatter_update(X,[i],tf.log(train_data[i]))