# Save Keras Values Layers from Concatenation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to Store the Concatenation Values for offline use in my model..

I need to save, load and loop though the CNN concatenation feature.

```
 class DCNN(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, nb_filters=50, FFN_units=512, nb_classes=2, dropout_rate=0.1, name="dncc"):
    super(DCNN, self).__init__(name=name)

    self.bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1",trainable=False)

    self.feature_size = nb_filters * len([2, 3, 4])
    self.num_filters_total = nb_filters * len([2, 3, 4])

    # self.features_before = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3, self.feature_size], name="features_before")
    self.features_before = [] #K.placeholder(shape=(None, 3, self.feature_size), name="features_before")

    self.bigram = layers.Conv1D(filters=nb_filters,
                                kernel_size=2,
                                padding='valid',
                                activation='relu')

    self.trigram = layers.Conv1D(filters=nb_filters,
                                 kernel_size=3,
                                 padding='valid',
                                 activation='relu')

    self.fourgram = layers.Conv1D(filters=nb_filters,
                                  kernel_size=5,
                                  padding='valid',
                                  activation='relu')

    self.pool = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()

    self.dense1 = layers.Dense(units=FFN_units, activation='relu')

    self.dropout = layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)

    if nb_classes == 2:
        self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')
    else:
        self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=nb_classes, activation='softmax')

def embed_with_bert(self,all_tokens):
    #first: all sentence , second: tokens accesss = get ids:0 masks:1 segments:2
    _, embds = self.bert_layer([all_tokens[:,0,:],
                               all_tokens[:,1,:],
                               all_tokens[:,2,:]])
    return embds

def call(self, inputs):

    x = self.embed_with_bert(inputs)
    x_1 = self.bigram(x)
    x_1 = self.pool(x_1)  # dim = batchsize x nb_filters

    x_2 = self.trigram(x)
    x_2 = self.pool(x_2)  # dim = batchsize x 50

    x_3 = self.fourgram(x)
    x_3 = self.pool(x_3)  # dim = batchsize x 50

    merged = tf.concat([x_1, x_2, x_3], axis=1)  # batchsize x 3*nb_filters = batchsize x 150

    h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(merged, [-1, self.num_filters_total])

    # features_before: list, 3D tensor of [batch_size, timestep_size, feature_size]
    # [batch_size, timestep_size, feature_size]
    t = tf.math.log(tf.expand_dims(h_pool_flat, axis=1))
    self.features_before.append(t)


    merged = self.dense1(merged)


    merged = self.dropout(merged)

    output = self.last_dense(merged)

    return output

def inference(self):
    return ft.stack(self.features_before)
```

I tried this:
[Making a list and appending to it in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518744/making-a-list-and-appending-to-it-in-tensorflow)

but I get the following error:

> ValueError: Tensor("dncc/Log:0", shape=(None, 1, 96), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("dncc/Log:0", shape=(None, 1, 96), dtype=float32).

What should I do to fix this error

Comment: Can you please clarify your requirement? Do you want to create a list and keep adding values to it in every iteration OR you want to save a variable to disk?

Comment: I want to do both, after every epoch I want to store the values. then, I want to create a file from returned stacked variables in inference

Comment: Can you change `ft.stack` to `tf.stack` and also can you please share the complete code OR a reproducible code for the error?

Comment: here is the code https://github.com/Rababalkhalifa/BERT : in bert_utils.py you can see the other model commented that I am trying to rewrite

Comment: There seems to be indentation error when code was copied to Colab  - `File "<ipython-input-1-4f3571338aef>", line 106
    super(DCNN, self).__init__(name=name)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block`. Can you please create a Google colab file with the code and the error and share the link.

Comment: Hi, I can see Bert.Exp.ipynb colab file, but all cells have ran fine and I don't find the error you have mentioned in the question in colab file. Anyway have provided solution below. Kindly utilize the same in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `callbacks` functionality in `model.fit()`. A custom callback is a powerful tool to customize the behavior of a Keras model during training, evaluation, or inference, including reading/changing the Keras model.

Here in the below program, I have created a simple model. In the model, we are capturing the `layers[2]` weights before every `epoch` begins in a `list`. I have created list called `my_list`, and capturing the weights before every epoch begin using `on_epoch_begin` of `callbacks`. I am using `append` to add to the list the new epoch weights. At the end, I have converted this `list` to a `ndarray` for simplicity.

**Note :** You can download the dataset I am using in the program from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv).

**Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
# MLP for Pima Indians Dataset saved to single file
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json

# load pima indians dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt("/content/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Model Summary
model.summary()

my_list = []

# Define the Required Callback Function
class ListAppend(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
      weights = model.layers[2].get_weights()[0]
      my_list.append(weights)

listappend = ListAppend() 

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0, callbacks = [listappend])

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# (7) Convert to a 2 dimensiaonal array of (epoch, gradients) type
my_list = np.asarray(my_list)
print("my_list Array has the shape:",my_list.shape)
```

**Output -**

```
1.15.2
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 12)                108       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 104       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_26 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 9         
=================================================================
Total params: 221
Trainable params: 221
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
acc: 78.26%
my_list Array has the shape: (150, 8, 1)
```

You can refer this official tensorflow [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback) to understand more about different methods available in `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback`. You can refer this official tensorflow [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback) for Keras custom callbacks example.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.